# Copy-Item doesn't work with square bracket in destination parameter

Tags: powershell, square-bracket, copy-item

I am trying to copy a file from a folder to another using

```
Copy-Item  $source -Destination $destination
```

but in $destination I have square brackets: Copy-Item doesn't throw an error but doesn't copy too.
It doesn't work if I replace square brackets with backtick (one or two backticks is the same)

```
if ($destination-match "\[") {
                $destination= $destination-replace "\[", "``["
            }
if ($destination-match "]") {
                $destination= $destination-replace "]", "``]"
            }
```

neither if I use

```
$destination = [Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($path)
```

. Does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @iRon you are right: there were square brackets in $source too!

Comment: Yes, I've read it but I've thought I don't have any square brackets in my original path. Thanks a lot @iRon